# Get indices of top N values sorted in descending order in matlab sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am extremely new to the matlab programming language and am trying to accomplish the following task:

```
   (1,3)       0.0000
   (2,3)       0.0000
   (3,3)       0.0000
   (4,3)       0.4803
   (5,3)       0.0000
   (6,3)       0.0000
   (7,3)       0.0000
   (8,3)       0.0000
   (9,3)       0.0030
  (10,3)       0.0000
  (11,3)       0.0000
```

The above matrix is a sparse column vector (only a part of which is shown above) of values most of which are zero. I would like to get the indices of the values sorted in descending order which would basically give me the positive non-zero values (there are no negative values in the vector!) in descending order along with their corresponding indices. I would like to know how to achieve this in matlab. I tried the sort function in matlab and it seems to sort the values but doesn't keep track of the indices which are also equally crucial. I also looked at sortrows function but doesn't seem to work for me. I tried the following code which was from another question at SO (unfortunately I am unable to find it again in order to cite it here):

```
A = sparse([0,1,2;3,4,5;6,7,8])
[sortValues,sortIndex] = sort(A(:),'descend');
```

Output:

```
sortValues =

   (1,1)        8
   (2,1)        7
   (3,1)        6
   (4,1)        5
   (5,1)        4
   (6,1)        3
   (7,1)        2
   (8,1)        1 

    sortIndex =

         9
         6
         3
         8
         5
         2
         7
         4
         1
```

In this case I don't know how to make use of the sortIndex to retrieve the original indices of the sorted values. Any help would be much appreciated.

Just to be clear the output that I am looking for in the above case of the sparse matrix would
be:

```
(4,3)     0.4803
(9,3)     0.0030
........  0.0000
........  0.0000
........  0.0000
etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 [I,J,S]=find(A);

 result=sortrows([I,J,S],-3);
```